# OpenGL: Use of multiple programs -> nothing drawn anymore

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rubymotion

I've generated multiple objects that are drawn properly with one program (i.e. one vertex shader and one fragment shader), which all run in the same context. I now wanted to add another object and I wanted to use it with a different program.

So, **before** calling `glActiveTexture()`, `glBindTexture()`,`glBindBuffer()`, `glBufferData()`, `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`, `glVertexAttribPointer()` and a few uniform commands, I call `glUseProgram()` with the appropriate programID.

The result is that nothing is drawn, when both kinds of objects are to be drawn. If I deactivate the objects that work with the first program, the new object is drawn properly and vice versa.

What are the things to bear in mind when switching programs.

Thanks.

**Edit:** When I investigated further, I noticed that an OpenGL error was thrown that I overlooked as it was consumed and not printed (*grrr*). As it turned out it wasn't an OpenGl mistake at all, but a rubymotion issue. (Didn't thought that at first.) Rubymotion garbage collected my OpenGL program, because I allocated it locally and only accessed it later over the `glUseProgram(GLuint x)`. So I just made the program global in ruby and all the programs are working properly now. Thanks for the comments, though. You couldn't have known, my mistake, sry.

Comment: Was any OpenGL error reported?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not. program also seems to run normally (updates are calculated)

Comment: The problem is usually caused by missing one small thing, like setting value for uniform from another shader. A code sample will really help in narrowing down your problem.

Comment: @keaukraine if you use another shader, do you have to set the uniforms for the other/first shader as well?? that seems kind of illogical to me.

Comment: Yes, you need to set it for each program... Can you imagine how much trouble could you create if 1 uniform could apply to all the programs? And in most cases you don't even have the same uniforms in multiple shader programs. Anyway: use program, push all the data you need, draw; repeat for another program. Note only that uniform states will be retained when switching between programs (you don't need to set the same color twice in program1 because you changed it in program2)

Comment: ChristophEberhardt, of course you should set uniforms for each shader separately. @MaticOblak, thank you for explaining this too :)

Comment: I'd love to see this code, or some version of it!  I haven't seen many OpenGL-on-RubyMotion examples yet.